# Enable Internet Facing FTP Server in AWS Transfer Family, using Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb, aws-transfer-family

Can anyone please lead me to aws docs or any other resource, that would help me with the steps to create an "internet" facing FTP server through AWS transfer family? I have learnt that the internal facing VPC should be associated with a network load balancer. Can someone please guide me through the step by step process to associate an internal facing VPC with a network load balancer?

Edit: Details on subnets where aws transfer family server is deployed in.

[Server Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYQij.png)

[Public Subnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtGqv.png)

Comment: Just create it in a public subnet and set up the security groups to allow traffic from the internet. No need for a network load balancer.

Comment: Thank you @Maurice for taking time to answer the question. I followed the instructions from this [blog](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/05/30/aws-create-a-vpc-with-public-and-private-subnets-and-a-nat-gateway). Tentatively I  I associated a security group that would accept all TCP connections from any IPv4 address (0.0.0.0/0). 

1. I associated the so created VPC with my FTP server endpoint.
2. Used the elastic IPv4 address as host in my FTP client (FIleZilla) and was not able to connect to the server.

I am a newbie with aws, please let me know if I am doing something wrong here ^^^.

Comment: Make sure the server is placed in the public subnet, otherwise changes to the security group won't help you. Only the public subnet is reachable via the internet.

Comment: Hello @Maurice, thank you for the time spent on this issue. I have edited the question by adding two screenshots, first screenshot with the information of subnets where server is deployed in and second screenshot with the information about one of the subnet's itself. Latter screenshot is of a subnet that is public. This do mean I have placed my server in a public subnet right?